# Unable to get URI from storage reference on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get an image URI that is stored in Firebase storage, in order to process it using another method.
I'm using the following:

```
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(this.getString(R.string.storage_path));
    Uri uri = storageRef.child("groups/pizza.png").getDownloadUrl().getResult();
```

and getting an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the download URL for a file with:

```
storageRef.child("groups/pizza.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // TODO: handle uri
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

See the [Firebase documentation for downloading data via a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,
I actually tried that, but getting at error on the "OnFailureListener" - Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnFailureListener' must either be declared abstract or implemented abstract method 'onFailure (Exception' in 'OnFailureListener'
I'm quite new to Firebase and coding in general, and i'd love to know what i'm missing.

Comment: Instead of "Throwable throwable", that should say "Exception exception" as the argument for onFailure.

Comment: Also, the reason you got the original exception is that the method is asynchronous and should be called the way Frank did.

Comment: @BenjaminWulfe Good catch on both cases. I'll make a note to update the documentation.

Comment: I have .sqlite file coming from the firebase. how to download it on success? @FrankvanPuffelen