# Download url from Firebase Storage is "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@441922b", doesn't display

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

i have to upload certain INFO into realtime database. All details AREuploaded correctly into it except image url which is uploaded as com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@****. The file is uploaded in the storage correctly. Codes are added as below.

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.firebase1;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import java.io.IOException;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Folder path for Firebase Storage.
    String Storage_Path = "All_Image_Uploads/";

    // Root Database Name for Firebase Database.
    public static final String Database_Path = "All_Image_Uploads_Database";

    // Creating button.
    Button ChooseButton, UploadButton, DisplayImageButton;

    // Creating EditText.
    EditText ImageName ;

    // Creating ImageView.
    ImageView SelectImage;

    // Creating URI.
    Uri FilePathUri;

    // Creating StorageReference and DatabaseReference object.
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    // Image request code for onActivityResult() .
    int Image_Request_Code = 7;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Assign FirebaseStorage instance to storageReference.
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        // Assign FirebaseDatabase instance with root database name.
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

        //Assign ID'S to button.
        ChooseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonChooseImage);
        UploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonUploadImage);

        DisplayImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DisplayImagesButton);

        // Assign ID's to EditText.
        ImageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ImageNameEditText);

        // Assign ID'S to image view.
        SelectImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ShowImageView);

        // Assigning Id to ProgressDialog.
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        // Adding click listener to Choose image button.
        ChooseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Creating intent.
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                // Setting intent type as image to select image from phone storage.
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please Select Image"), Image_Request_Code);

            }
        });


        // Adding click listener to Upload image button.
        UploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Calling method to upload selected image on Firebase storage.
                UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage();

            }
        });


        DisplayImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayImagesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            FilePathUri = data.getData();

            try {

                // Getting selected image into Bitmap.
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);

                // Setting up bitmap selected image into ImageView.
                SelectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                // After selecting image change choose button above text.
                ChooseButton.setText("Image Selected");

            }
            catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Creating Method to get the selected image file Extension from File Path URI.
    public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

        // Returning the file Extension.
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri)) ;

    }

    // Creating UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage method to upload image on storage.
    public void UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage() {

        // Checking whether FilePathUri Is empty or not.
        if (FilePathUri != null) {

            // Setting progressDialog Title.
            progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

            // Showing progressDialog.
            progressDialog.show();

            // Creating second StorageReference.
            StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(Storage_Path + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));

            // Adding addOnSuccessListener to second StorageReference.
            storageReference2nd.putFile(FilePathUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            // Getting image name from EditText and store into string variable.
                            String TempImageName = ImageName.getText().toString().trim();

                            // Hiding the progressDialog after done uploading.
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            // Showing toast message after done uploading.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                            ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(TempImageName, taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString());

                            // Getting image upload ID.
                            String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();

                            // Adding image upload id s child element into databaseReference.
                            databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageUploadInfo);
                        }
                    })
                    // If something goes wrong .
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                            // Hiding the progressDialog.
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            // Showing exception erro message.
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })

                    // On progress change upload time.
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            // Setting progressDialog Title.
                            progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

                        }
                    });
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Select Image or Add Image Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}
```

Sample database URL com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@441922b

This is my Activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Firebase Image Upload Tutorial"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/ShowImageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonChooseImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ShowImageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Choose Image"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ImageNameEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonChooseImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter Image Name Here"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonUploadImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageNameEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Upload image to Firebase Storage"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/DisplayImagesButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonUploadImage"
        android:text="Show All Uploaded Images"/>
```

I will Also Appreciate Help in Displaying All Images in RecyclerView Vertically or Horizontally

Comment: You are not using getDownloadUrl correctly.  Please see the marked duplicate for details.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Doug. Kindly assist how to implement the answers referenced in my code. I don't see where the said answer's match in my code. Thanks.

Comment: It's the same problem.  Use the answer in the other question to learn how to use getDownloadUrl correctly.

Comment: The crux is that you'll need to do `taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener`. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42444292, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369445, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51064689, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219540

Comment: No Success still!

Comment: I made it guys. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!!!. "Train Hard Code Easy". @Frank van Puffelen thanks more for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218220/android-firebase-uploading-images-wrong-url-problem-x-goog-upload-comment-head/54219540#54219540

Comment: You're welcome 